# I searched "Amazon.com" in Opera quicksearch and it led me to a strange page

Tags: malware

I searched "amazon.com" in Opera quicksearch and it led me to this site: `http://iyfnzgb.com/?pid=9PO1H9V71&dn=amanzon.com`
Is it malicious? Opera didn't open a proper internet page, only a screen with the opera logo. In the History it shows a directory icon.

Comment: Perhaps you have an adware addon installed on your browser.....................?

Comment: I have installed only LastPass, Opera Ad blocker and User-Agent Switcher. I am running a scan with MalwareBytes.

Comment: You searched for "amanzon.com"

Comment: We cannot do a site analysis for you. Please submit to the scanner of your choice, like VirusTotal.com